# Parent gradle module with java-platform plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, maven-bom

I have the following build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java-platform'
}
subprojects {
    configurations {
        deployerJars
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}
publications {
    myPlatform(MavenPublication) {
        from components.javaPlatform
    }
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
    }
}
```

And i'm receiving that error:

`> Could not get unknown property 'javaPlatform' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.`

Couldn't find any information about this error, and from what I understand from the [platform plugin page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html), you cannot set a project with 'java' plugin a 'java-platform' plugin, but this is not the case.
I'd appreciate some guidance here, thanks.

Comment: Why you edited your question similar to the solution in the answer, it is quite confusing...

Comment: @DanielHári, I have no idea why I did it, it was long time ago, anyway i've rolledback this change, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publications` must be inside the `publishing` block. And you can't use `from components.java` since your project isn't a Java project, but a platform. So it should be

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java-platform'
}
subprojects {
    configurations {
        deployerJars
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        myPlatform(MavenPublication) {
            from components.javaPlatform
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Event after changing, I still have the same error.
I have edited the question with the new details.

Comment: You have this error when doing what? Copying and pasting this to a build.gradle file of a simple probject (with no subproject) and executing ./gradlew tasks runs fine.

Comment: I notice that you edited your question, but are still not using the correct code. Read my answer carefully.